# Typecasting methods with "instanceof"

Tags: java, arrays, class, polymorphism, instanceof

So I'm running into some problems setting up some methods, I've been staring at the computer screen for too long. I'm having difficulty with 4 of the 5 methods. The last two methods need to call for a CompSciStudent class, hence the use of the 'instanceof' because not all Students in the array are CompSciStudents. Those two methods need to add a CS language to a Student in the Student array, and the other one is to check to see how many CompSciStudents in the array know a specific language. The other two methods deal with the whole array. The first one is to add just a test score to a specific student in a certain position, each student in the array will have a specific name when called in the array. The last method is getting the average average test score. The method is to call the average test score from both Students and CompSciStudents in the array and average each separately then take the average of those averages. Take a look at the Class structure:

```
public class School {

    private Student[] theStudents;

    public School() {
        this.theStudents = new Student[] { null };// needs to start out as empty
    }

    /*
     * next two methods would allow a user to add or drop a student into the
     * student array for the school ??Also with Enroll student, should be able
     * to assign a class to the student, i.e. Calculas, history, etc??
     */
    public void enrollStudent(Student newStudent) {
        Student totalStudents[] = new Student[theStudents.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
            totalStudents[i] = theStudents[i];
        }
        totalStudents[theStudents.length] = newStudent;
        theStudents = totalStudents;
    }

    public void dropStudent(Student dropStudent) {
        Student totalStudents[] = new Student[theStudents.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i > theStudents.length; i--) {
            totalStudents[i] = theStudents[i];
        }
        totalStudents[theStudents.length] = dropStudent;
        theStudents = totalStudents;
    }

    // add Test Score for a student
    public double addTestScore(String newStudent, double testScore) {
        testScores[posi] = testScore;
    }

    /*
     * count the number of students in a given class, not the school
     */
    public int countClassSize(String course) {
        // Need to access how the course names are stored for the school to
        // count this size.
        String courseName;
        if (this.courseName.equals(course)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < theStudents.length; i++) {
                int count = count + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  get average average score of the student array
     *  The student array is made up of Regular students and
     *  CompSciStudents. The average should take the average of
     *  both the average score for Students and average score of 
     *  CompSciStudents and return the average average.
     */

    public double averageAverageScore(String course) {
        double averageCourseScore;
        if(this.theStudents.equals(course)/2){
            return averageCourseScore;
        }

    }

    /*
     * add a programming language to only CS students at the school Will need to
     * use the instanceof for proper type casting
     */
    public String addProgrammingLanguage(String studentName, String programLanguage) {
        for (int i = 0; i ; i++);
        if (this.theStudents[i] instanceof CompSciStudent);
            CompSciStudent tempStudent = (CompSciStudent)this.theStudents[i];
                tempStudent.knowsLanguage(knowThisLanguage);

    }

    /*
     * Count the number of students in the school that know a certain
     * programming language, again will need to typecast properly
     */
    public int numberThatKnowLanguage(String programLanguage) {
        for();
                if(this.theStudents[i] instanceof CompSciStudent);
                CompSciStudent tempStudent = (CompSciStudent)this.theStudents[i];
                    tempStudent.learnedLanguage(knowThisLanguage);

    }
```

Comment: disctinct class for Students having one group of skill seems poor design. This is not polymorphism situation, use other pattern.

Comment: could you describe which problem you do have with these method? Also add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question please.

Comment: (1) With dropStudent one needs an index in theStudents and another index in totalStudents, as when one encounters the student to be removed, the theStudents' index is increased, the totalStudents' index not. (2) The `int count = 0;` must be placed before the for-loop.

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: `new Student[] { null };` is not empty, it's a size-1 array with null element; empty would be `new Student[0];`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you are facing is with the design of your application. I'll suggest few design improvements which should help you in solving your problems.

1. Rather than declaring `theStudents[]` as an array, make it a List like `List<Student> students`. This will substantially reduce the extra effort which you are putting in while enrolling a student and dropping a student.
2. Adding subjects for a student using an explicit method call should not be the ideal case. Subjects should be strongly associated with a particular student. In order to adhere to design principles, Student object should be designed in such a way that, "Student **has-a** name, **has-a** id, **has** subjects". Take care of adding the subjects while creating a student object. So this eliminates the need of adding an extra method.
3. Categorizing a student as a Computer Science student, Electronics Student etc. should be handled in a separate class say let's call it as **Department**. Now say for the sake of simplicity, we will consider only two departments. One be **Computer Science** and another be **Electronics**. "Each department **has** students". By design principles(**has-a** relation), you should be creating a `List<Student> students` (like mentioned in point no. 1.) in your department class and finally your School class will have a `List<Department> departments`. It's one to many relation.
4. Don't forget to override `hashCode()` and `equals(Object obj)` methods as they'll be necessary while comparing two or more `Student` objects.

So now, you can say that "`School` **has** departments. Each `Department` **has** students. Each `Student` **has** subjects".

And now your classes should somewhat look like this:

```
public class School {
    private List<Department> departments;
    /*
     * All your methods and constructors goes here.
     */
}

public class Department {
    private List<Student> students;
    /*
     * All your methods and constructors goes here.
     */
}

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String courseStream;
    private List<String> subjects;
    /*
     * All your methods and constructors goes here.
     */
}
```

**Note**: I'm not saying that this is a perfect design. But it is quite subtle for the scenario which you have explained. Again, code design might vary from person to person.